# How to get a length of json object saved in local project directory?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, java-io

I have spring-boot project and my project's structure looks like this...

```
-src
-target
-pom.xml
-uploaded_json
 -- example.json
```

and here is my example.json

```
[
    {
        "Username": "U1",
        "Password": "P1",
    },
    {
        "Username": "U2",
        "Password": "P2",
    },
    {
        "Username": "U3",
        "Password": "P3",
    }  
]
```

Can I read example.json and save it as int type variable? Should I use java.io.File Object? Please help me to figure out how to get the length of JSON file. Thank you in advance.

Edit: I made a method using simple-json.

```
@GetMapping("getJSON")
    public String testmethod() {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        File directory = new File(".");
        JSONArray a;
        try {
            a = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader(
                    directory.getCanonicalPath() + "\\uploaded_json\\example.json"));
            int length = a.size();
            System.out.println(length);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by length in this case? Is it 3 because there are 3 objects in the JSON list? Or do you mean the size of the file in bytes

Comment: @Joni I meant the length of array so in that case what I want to get is 3. Sorry, I did not clarify what I want.

Comment: You'll need to read the file and parse the JSON content. Do you already use a JSON parser library in your project? If so, which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `jackson-databind library`, using the class `JsonNode`.

The latest version on the maven repository is 2.11.1

```
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.11.1'
```

Here is an example for getting the size with `jackson-databind`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class GradleApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    

        try {
            File jsonFile = Paths.get("src", "main", "resources", "example.json").toFile();
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(jsonFile);
            System.out.println("The size of the json is : "+ node.size());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks simple compared to my edited method using simple-json. Could you check if you can simplify my method above because I'm not used to json lib and I don't know that is the right one.(It returns the right size of the json array though)

Comment: @loone96, it looks fine, i would suggest loading the json only one time, if the file does not change, for a webservice, loading the file each time consumes resources

Comment: For some function in my application, I need length value of json. Should I save length value into my database as json file uploaded into my server?

Comment: I would add a static class or spring bean, initialize the json file in a class attribute with the . The file will be loaded only one time, and you can use the class attribue to get the size. Use spring @postConstruct if you choose to use a spring bean to initialize the class attribue.